# Pipe process not terminate

Tags: c, shell, process, pipe

I implemented pipes while implementing myshell.

The process for entering the pipe has dup2 (fd[pcount][WRITEEND] ,STDOUT_FILENO)
The process of receiving input from the pipe has dup2 (fd[pcount-1][READEND, STDIN_FILENO])
And I closed all fds.

And I ran all the processes and closed all the pipe fd left in the parent process.

And when *ls | grep c* was entered in the command, an error such as g*rep: (standard input): Bad file descriptor* occurred. What would be the problem? I closed all the fds.

** Edited:

As you said, I modified some of the codes. I brought the main program
and I Changed the Bitwise operator(~) to '!' and it solved a lot of problems (I think I've lost my composure after spending a long night looking at the code)

There is a final problem. In the background, the program runs without any problems, but in the foreground, grep does not exit after printing the results.

For *ls | grep.c*, the result are printed, but grep is not terminated.

I'd appreciate it if you could guess which part could be the problem.

The problem has changed, so I have revised the title.
**

```
   int main(void){
    int idx = 0; 
    bool pipe_start_flag = false; 

    char cmdline[MAXLINE]; /* Command line */

    while (1) {
    /* Read */
        // init global variable(pcount, reap_count)
        pcount = 0; reap_count = 0; 

        printf("> ");                   
        fgets(cmdline, MAXLINE, stdin); 
        if (feof(stdin))
            exit(0);

        /* Evaluate */
        eval(cmdline);
    }     
}


void eval(char *cmdline){
        int idx = 0, pidx = 0;
        char * argv[MAXARGS];
        char buffer[MAXARGS];
        char * envp[2] = {"/usr/bin/", "0"}; 
        int fd[MAXPIP][2]; 


        bool pipe_start_flag = false; // this argv print output to the WriteEnd of Pipe; 
        bool pipe_end_flag = false; // this argv input from ReadEnd of Pipe
        
 
        bg = preproc_command(cmdline, &idx); 
        strcpy(buffer, cmdline);  

        while(buffer[idx] != '\0'){
                
            /*check if it is piped process*/
            pipe_start_flag = pipe_end_flag;  // if last process was piping process, then this process is a piped process

            parse_line(&buffer[idx], argv, &idx, &pipe_end_flag); // parse until it meets '\0' or '|'(assign its (index-1) on idx)
            if(pipe_end_flag) // if there is '|' character we set pipe
                pipe(fd[pcount]); 

            if(!builtin_command(argv)){
                pid[pcount] = Fork(); 
                if(pid[pcount] == 0){
                    if(pipe_end_flag){ 
                       dup2(fd[pcount][WRITEEND],STDOUT_FILENO); 
                    }
                    if(pipe_start_flag){
                        dup2(fd[pcount-1][READEND] ,STDIN_FILENO); 
                    }
                    for(int i = 0; i < pcount; i++){
                        close(fd[i][READEND]); 
                        close(fd[i][WRITEEND]); 
                    }
                    if(!pipe_start_flag || pipe_end_flag){ // if it is not the last process
                        close(fd[pcount][READEND]);
                        close(fd[pcount][WRITEEND]); 
                    }

                // we should get input from fd[READEND] and put it on argv 
                execvp(argv[0], argv); 
        
            }
            else{ // parent proce
                if(!bg){
                    pidx = waitpid(-1, NULL, WUNTRACED);
                }
                else{ // background process
                }
                ++pcount; 
            }
            ++idx; 
        }   
        if(pipe_start_flag){ // close pipe in main process
            for(int i = 1; i < pcount ; i++){
                close(fd[i-1][READEND]);
                close(fd[i-1][WRITEEND]);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Tangential: `if(~pipe_start_flag || pipe_end_flag){` it is more usual to use the `!` (logical negation)  operator than the `~` (bitwise complement) operator.

Comment: Also tangential: you don't need to test the result of the `exec*()` family of functions.  If they succeed, they don't return; if they return, they failed.  It's also a good practice to report errors to `stderr` rather than `stdout`.

Comment: Probably relevant: your `if (execvp(argv[0], argv) < 0)` code is executed regardless of whether we're in the child or in the parent.  I believe you should only be doing that in the child.  It's also not clear what the `else` block for `if (!builtin_command(arg v)` is doing.  It doesn't seem to execute the built-in command, and it messes around with `if (!bg)` etc.  I think this is misplaced too.  It may be a consequence of conversion from your real code to an SO question.  We need you to provide an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you, some modifications have been made to the code. I'd appreciate it if you could take a look.

Comment: This is still not a [mre].  There are calls to multiple functions that do not appear, references to variables / macros that are nowhere declared, *etc*..  No, we do not want to see all that, but rather we want you to *dummy it up*.

Comment: At first glance, however, you are over-closing your file descriptors, though that might not bite you when there are only two commands in a pipeline.  File descriptor numbers get re-used, and in the code presented, that can lead to some of your pipe ends getting closed before you are done with them.